# How do I create a .vba file?

Tags: vba

I need to save a file as a .vba on my windows computer, but have no idea how to go about it. Can anyone help?

I

Comment: there is no .vba file... if you want to use excel vba then the file has to be .xlsm. For what do you want to use this file?

Comment: Are you sure you mean VBA? Can you give us some more context to this?

Answer (score 1):

You should save your file as ".xlsm"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don t you mean VBS? cos vba is not a file extension.. vba = vb for applications, you need to specify which office app? outlook, excel, access?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file through excel application and save as ".xlsm" extension.

Answer (score 0):

It can either be saved as an .xlsm file, or you can copy the code to Notepad or editor and save it as a text file for convenient storage. The "xlsm" means "macro- enabled workbook"